# Downloading image from firebase storage using picasso: out of memory exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, picasso, android-bitmap

I am working on an android app which needs to download images from firebase backend but after downloading and showing 5 to 6 images in my recyler view, out of memory exception is thrown.

**I have used an image compressing library due to which the size of each image is nearly 300 to 400 KB.**

> I have added `<application
>        android:largeHeap="true"` but still there is same issue

My code :

```
//Retriving image from picasso
            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(c);
            builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(c,exception.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            Picasso pic = builder.build();
            pic.load(currentPost.getDownloadlinkDB()).into(((MyViewHolder_Image) holder).imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Problem in downloading image from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Snapshot of the exception
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Give `Glide` a try. It stores the resized imaged rather than the original and uses RGB565

Comment: Image size in KB does not matter at all. Only resolution matters.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Manifest file. Inside application tag

```
<application
     android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: It has been added already, it only increase the downloading of two more images but that is not enough.

Comment: try to increase the cache size for picasso

Comment: Picasso p = new Picasso.Builder(context)
    .memoryCache(new LruCache(24000))
    .build();

Comment: Wow!! It works...
But we set the memoryCache maxSize statically, how to set it dynamically means the app can itself decide how much size needed for Picasso

Comment: need to check. Also need to check its impact on increasing to max cache size.